# Position of a ListView item onTouch

Tags: android, listview, position, touch-event, listviewitem

Is there a way to get the position of a ListView child onTouch ACTION_DOWN event?

```
listView.getChildAt(position_when_touched).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newBackground);
```

Comment: You can use the ListView's methods pointToPosition and getFirstVisiblePosition to do that... but why do you want to do that? If you want to change the background of a ListView item on touch, you can do so by setting a selector as the list item's bg.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into that. The thing is that I have multiple lists in my layout where I synchronize their movement by dispatchevent so when I set a selector I get multiple effects, so I need to specifically change the background on touch down.